# How to open a Jupyter notebook on browser from AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open on my local browser the Jupyter notebook opened through the AWS instance.

I am using m4.2xlarge instance from the ami-d36386aa, Ireland region.

I then typed inside the instance command line:

1. jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=xx.xx.xx.xx

Where the ip is the public ip from AWS.

2. run Jupyter notebook

given output: 
http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/?token=....

3. I copied the output from (2) to my browser but nothing is happening.

Any suggestions?